What are the consequences of specifying multiple `ClientTransportPlugin`s?
I have a question regarding Tor bridges. I understand that one can specify multiple Tor bridges in Tor Browser or when one runs Tor using command line. Now, my question is whether one can (and should) mix Tor bridge types. To illustrate it a bit more, say that I specify
--ClientTransportPlugin "webtunnel exec path/webtunnel-client.exe"
and
--ClientTransportPlugin "snowflake exec path/snowflake-client.exe"
and a few bridges of either type using --Bridge argument.
My understanding is that Tor will work with the settings but using multiple Tor bridge plugins might possibly affect my privacy. Is that true? Is there any other thing to be aware of when using multiple Tor bridge plugins?

It's totally OK to specify multiple transport types, so you can have like you're writing: one plugin for each transport type. After that it will be used when the bridge of the type described is added. Your understanding is correct! There's nothing transport-plugin-specific to be worried about, just as usual: no unnecessary permissions, suid/sgid e.t.c...
